# how can be call uses library in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

how can be call uses a library in CakePHP 3

```
namespace App\Utility;

use Cake\I18n\Time;

class Adwords
{

    /**
     * Get the Library For Adwords.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCampaign()
    {
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\CampaignService;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\OrderBy;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Paging;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Selector;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\SortOrder;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\FrequencyCap;
    }

    public function removeCampaign()
    {
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Campaign;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\CampaignOperation;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\CampaignService;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\CampaignStatus;
        use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Operator;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get when you try this code? Likely, what you want is a single `use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm;` at the very top, next to the `Time` line, then you'll be able to create and reference objects of the required types.

Comment: when we use in component below code  require_once(APP.'Utility'.DS.'Adwords.php');
        $this->AdWords = new AdWords();
        $this->AdWords->getCampaign();

        $campaignService = $adWordsServices->get($session, CampaignService::class); it gives     syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Comment: Yeah, that would be because you can't use `use` inside a function. It should go at the top of the file, as I said.